# Bot Framework serviceUrl

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a Notification Only bot to enable proactive Teams notifications.

As far as I am aware it is necessary to store the ServiceUrl from an incoming message to the bot endpoint. I have read that it is also possible that service Url can change in the future (although unlikely) and that if this happens the serviceUrl should be updated and used for future messages.

Using a test O365 instance in UK region I see the following behaviour:

When I add member to team or install the app to a team, the service Url comes through as:
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/uk/

When I remove a member from team or remove the app from team, the service Url comes through as:
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/

If our service tries to send a notification via the rest api, using the /emea ServiceUrl it returns a 403 Forbidden

Doing the same using an O365 instance in US region the service Url is allways:
https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/

Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Are there any rules on when the Service Url should be updated and when it should not?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Checking it internally.

Comment: Hi, just wondered if there was any update on this? Thanks.

Comment: I need your BotID, region where this is happening and approximate time frame. This will help me check the logs.

Comment: Hi @Abhijit-MSFT. Does the serviceUrl remains same for a tenant-Id or it can vary from user to user within same company? I need to send proactive messages to users, fetch list of users from a given team-id and I'm not sure which serviceUrl to use.